# gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound

Tags: google-api, gspread

I am writing a python(ver 3) script to access google doc using gspread.

```
  1)  import gspread
  2)  from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
  3)  scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
  4)  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(r'/path/to/jason/file/xxxxxx.json',scope)
  5)  gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
  6)  wks = gc.open("test").sheet1
```

**test** is a **google sheet** which seems to be opened and read fine but if I try to read from a Office excel file it gives me error.here is what they look: [image]

The folder which test and mtg are under is shared with the email I got in json file.Also both files were shared with that email.

Tried:

```
wks = gc.open("mtg.xls").sheet1
```

and

```
wks = gc.open("mtg.xls").<NameOfFirstSheet>
```

and

```
wks = gc.open("mtg").<NameOfFirstSheet>
```

error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/client.py",
>   line 152, in open
>       raise SpreadsheetNotFound gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `.xls` to be added at the end of the file name, the data is saved in a different format (and can later be exported as `.xls`).

Try to break your code into:

```
ss = open("MTG_Collection_5_14_16") 
ws = ss.worksheet("<NameOfFirstSheet>")
```

and post the error message if any.

`Spreadsheet` instances have an attribute `sheet1` because it is the default name for the first worksheet. `ss.sheet1` actually returns the worksheet with index 0, no matter what its name is.

If you want to access another worksheet, you need to use one of `ss.worsheet("<title>")` or `ss.get_worksheet(<index>)`. `ss.<NameOfFirstSheet>` will not work.

Comment: thanks ...Lines 1 to 5  then added these :
ss=gc.open("mgt")
ws=ss.worksheet(<"nameOfFirstSheet">)
values = ws.row_values(1)
print(values) ---> failed with error:    ss=gc.open("mgt")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 152, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound

Comment: same code ran for test(google sheet doc) worked fine.

Comment: If you want to edit an `xls` file with gspread, you need to convert it to the google doc format first. If you try to open `mgt.xls` manually from the spreadsheet app interface, you will be asked if you want to open it as a view or create a copy with the same file name. Do the second and share the copy with the email address in the credential json file and then it should work.

Comment: Looks like I was not fully understood my need till now. I need to "access" to excel file "located under google drive", then open and read from it using xlrd library. gspread is not a way to achieve this correct?

Comment: You are correct. The way `gspread` is communicating with the spreadsheet is by forming URLs to request specific cells. This wouldn't work with an xls document on your drive. It should be quite easy to download a copy through the drive API though.

Answer (score 19):

I was getting this as I had missed step 4 [here](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html)

> Go to your spreadsheet and share it with a client_email from the step
>   above. Otherwise you’ll get a SpreadsheetNotFound exception when
>   trying to access this spreadsheet with gspread.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with my problem :)

Answer (score 7):

A Very Important Note from here : [https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#enable-api-access]

```
Very important! Go to your spreadsheet and share it with a client_email from the step above. Just like you do with any other Google account.
If you don’t do this, you’ll get a gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound exception when trying to access this spreadsheet from your application or a script.
```

This means that you need to share the spreadsheet *(by opening the spreadsheet and then clicking on the share button and then just paste the email id)* with the **"client_email"** mail id which is provided in the JSON file that you got from google developer console

eg:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "speeqedy-octane-317516",
  "private_key_id": "8ct0ad00e3e59d49a576012cb515ea89e4e49cc4",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nHB/iyGpo6KQBl/rRtcNxQXw=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "cybor@speedy-octane-313216.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "102481923285078876543",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/cybor%40speedy-octane-317516.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

if this is your JSON file then you need to copy the ***client_email*** that is
`cybor@speedy-octane-313216.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and then share your sheets to this email id.

Comment: Thank you , this one is worked for me.