# Why I got error "gspread.exceptions.NoValidUrlKeyFound" on python?

Tags: python, gspread

I`m new to pyhon and now trying to use google drive API.

I already enabled both Google sheet and Google drive API Access for this Project. and Here are my codes.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]

json_file_name = '/Users/kimjongyool/Desktop/upbeat-polygon-292119-fd2b4fab4fa1.json'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_file_name, scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SAci5Is4tQ1uETGKcTCUmBQrFz4C7-wmj3NhsYgKAWc/edit#gid=0'
doc = gc.open_by_url('spreadsheet_url')
```

If I run this, I get error message "gspread.exceptions.NoValidUrlKeyFound
"

Have searched here and there and still not found any solutions for it. Please help!

Comment: See [gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602460/gspread-exceptions-spreadsheetnotfound)

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code in this line:

```
doc = gc.open_by_url('spreadsheet_url')
```

The variable name should go without quote chars ('). This is corrected version:

```
doc = gc.open_by_url(spreadsheet_url)
```

Comment: Great, if you're happy with the answer, please mark it as accepted.